integration by part differential geometry
I am reading a differential geometry text, and got stuck on how to do integration by parts in differential geometry. Here is a simplified version of the text does. Suppose we want to calculate the following integral in a 3d volume. The volume is confined between two surfaces along n direction and the area of this surfaces is given by the area element $dA$, and the volume element is $dV$.
The integral reads
$\int T_{ij;n} B^{ij;n} dV$
where $T$ $B$ are rank two tensors, $n$ is the direction normal to the surfaces, and upper and lower indicies are as usual in differential geometry notation. The text writes this as a volume integral plus an integral on the surface. What I don't understand is how to write the surface part. They write it as
$\int T^{ij} B_{ij;n} dA$
To be more specific, I do not know why they only take the integration by part for the lower index and not the upper index derivative. I really appreciate it if someone could explain how integration by parts works in differential geometry.

Which book are you reading?

It is a paper. Can provide the link to the paper if that's helpful @Deane

If it's a published paper, then a reference is enough.

here is the link to the paper https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2017.0686. I do not understand how they get the area integral term in 4.5 from 4.2. @Deane

In particular, I do not know why the integration by part only is done on the covariant derivative and not on the upper derivative. @Deane

@Deane sorry there was a typo in my question in the second integral. I have modified it now

Integration by parts is based on the product rule. We have for example (no summation over $n$),
$$
(T_{ij} B^{ij;n})_{;n} 
= T_{ij;n} B^{ij;n} + T_{ij} B^{ij;n}_{;n},
$$
implying
$$
T_{ij;n} B^{ij;n} = (T_{ij} B^{ij;n})_{;n} - T_{ij} B^{ij;n}_{;n}.
$$
Applying integration over a region $\Omega=S\times[-h/2,h/2]$ we get
$$
\int_\Omega T_{ij;n} B^{ij;n} \, dV
= \int_\Omega (T_{ij} B^{ij;n})_{;n} \, dV - \int_\Omega T_{ij} B^{ij;n}_{;n} \, dV
.
$$
The first integral on the hand side can now be written
$$
\int_S dA \int_{-h/2}^{h/2} dt \, (T_{ij} B^{ij;n})_{;n}
$$
where $t$ runs in the direction of the normal of the shell, so the covariant derivative in the direction of the normal equals the derivative with respect to $t.$ The inner integral therefore becomes
$$
\left. T_{ij} B^{ij;n} \right|_{t=-h/2}^{h/2}
$$
so, applying the $A$-integral we get
$$
\left. \int_S dA \, T_{ij} B^{ij;n} \right|_{t=-h/2}^{h/2}
$$
i.e.
$$
\int_S dA \, T_{ij} B^{ij;n}
$$
over both sides of the shell.

But your final result does not match with the second integral in my question

@questionerno8. Are you referring to the position of the indices or to me having index ${}_n$ on $dA$?

Yes I am referring to the position of indicies

@TedShifrin. It looks like tensor notation using Einstein summation convention.

@questionerno8. If an index occurs in both upper and lower position in a tensor, and therefore is summed over, then you can raise the lower and lower the upper. For example, $T_{ij} B^{ij} = T^{ij} B_{ij}.$

but is this correct even when there is a derivative? say is $T_{ij}B^{ij;k}$ equal to $T^{ij}B_{ij;k}$?  The position of the derivative is also changes!

No, those are not equal. But I have $dA_n$ that has a lower tensor index matching the upper index ${}^{;n}.$ Then $B^{ij;n} , dA_n = B^{ij}{}_{;n} , dA^n.$

Modified my answer.
